# Can't find module named 'azure.datalake' or pip in Azure Notebook VM

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-virtual-machine

I've been using Notebook VMs through Machine Learning Studio for a while now, but they've suddenly started acting strange. For some time now I've experienced sudden error messages resulting in the VM not responding and having to be restarted. Even this in some cases did not help. Recently, these problems have seemed to disappear, but I now have a few other errors. I can't import the modules I need, for example:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------    
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-2f761c8f97ca> in <module>
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 
----> 5 from azure.datalake.store import core, lib
      6 
      7 pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.datalake'
```

Until now I've resolved this by using `!pip install`, but now I get the following message:

```
/bin/sh: 1: pip: not found
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I see you are using Notebook VM on Azure Machine Learning, as the figure below, it's a new preview feature of Azure Machine Learning.

[image]

And I got the same issue with yours when I tried to install `azure-datalake-store` via `!pip install azure-datalake-store`, as below.

[image]

My solution to install the Python package via `pip` is to open a terminal windown to run the command `pip install azure-datalake-store`.

Fig 1. New a terminal window

[image]

Fig 2. To run `pip install azure-datalake-store` in the terminal, and it installed the package successfully

[image]

Fig 3. Then I import the package installed by terminal successfully in `Python 3.6-Azure ML` and `Python 3` without any error

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps.

---

<s>It sounds like you have installed [`azure-datalake-store`](https://pypi.org/project/azure-datalake-store/) package on Azure Notebooks via command `!pip install azure-datalake-store` as the figure below.</s>

**Fig 1. Install `azure-datalake-store` via `!pip install` in my notebook for Python 3**

[image]

However, I see some accidentes broke down your notebook environment. Actually, in a worked notebook, you can see that it's an Anaconda environment via `!which pip` or `!which conda` to show the tools path.

**Fig 2. Check the path of tools `pip` or `conda`**

[image]

So first, you can try to check the conda tool whether exists via `!which conda`, and then to install `pip` tool again via `!conda install -y pip` as the figure below.

**Fig 3. Install `pip` via `conda`**

[image]

---

**Update**: Please command `!ls /home/nbuser` and `!ls /home/nbuser/anaconda<python-version>-<anaconda-version>` to see what there are, and command `!echo $PATH` to check your `PATH` value, as the figure below.

[image]

I guess you may only need to edit your `PATH` value to add the `/home/nbuser/anaconda<python-version>-<anaconda-version>/bin` as the figure above via run `!export PATH=/home/nbuser/anaconda<python-version>-<anaconda-version>/bin:$PATH` at the front of all code in the notebook to fix your issue.

Comment: @Haumann Try to command `!ls /home/nbuser/` and `!ls /home/nbuser/anaconda<python-version>-<anaconda-version>` to see what there are, and check your `$PATH` value via `!echo $PATH`. Please see my figure below in my updated post.

Comment: Hmm, I found conda with `!ls /anaconda/bin`, but `!export PATH=/anaconda/bin:$PATH` didn't change my `$PATH`?

Comment: There's no `nbuser` directory, `!ls /home` returns only: `azureuser  nxautomation`

Comment: @Haumann I think you were using https://notebooks.azure.com/ previously, but now I see you are using Notebook VM on Azure ML. So I update my post again, hope helps for you.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Any idea why `!pip` doesn't work anymore, though?

Comment: @Haumann I think the `!pip` issue is related to the startup script. If you have to use it, may you can try to check the content of jupyter related script files on Notebook VM and make the path of `pip` tool in the `PATH` environment.